# multidimensional String[][] array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that is from .split command and want to put it into an array called String[][] datatabvars, I do not know how to turn datatabvars into a two dimensional array and put the data into it.

```
public String[] getList() {
    String file_name = "path";
    String[] links = null;
    String[][] datatabvars = null; // this var
    int numberOfDatatabs = 0;
    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name); 
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
        for(i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) { //aryLines.length
            if (aryLines[i].substring(0, 7).equals("datatab")) {
                aryLines[i] = aryLines[i].replace("datatab["+Integer.toString(numberOfDatatabs)+"] = new Array(", "");
                aryLines[i] = aryLines[i].replace(");", "");
                datatabvars = aryLines[i].split(","); // this split array
                numberOfDatatabs++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(datatabvars[0]);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
    return links;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, arrays are to avoided like the plague - use collections if possible:. In this case, `split()` returns a `String[]`, so use that, but use `List<String[]>` to store multiple `String[]`:

```
List<String[]> datatabvars = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
String[] array = input.split(",");
datatabvars.add(array);
```

You find life is much easier using collections than arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Update the two lines(I added comment) as below: (I am assuming that rest of your code is working)

```
String[][] datatabvars = null; // this var
int numberOfDatatabs = 0;
try {
    ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name); 
    String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
    datatabvars = new String[aryLines.length][]; // INITIALIZED

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) { //aryLines.length
        if (aryLines[i].substring(0, 7).equals("datatab")) {
            aryLines[i] = aryLines[i].
                        replace("datatab["+Integer.toString(numberOfDatatabs)+"] = 
                                               new Array(", "");
            aryLines[i] = aryLines[i].replace(");", "");
            datatabvars[i] = aryLines[i].split(","); // this split array: ASSIGNED
            numberOfDatatabs++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(datatabvars[0]);
```

Comment: i tried using datatabvars[numberOfDatatabs] = aryLines[i].split(","); // this split shouldn't that create them as needed startign with 0, then goign as high as ti can?

Comment: You should definitely not assume the length or initialize the entire array when you then throw away the initialized length-10 array by assigning to datatabvars[i]. Rather, just do datatabvars = new String[aryLines.length][]; initializing just the outer array. The rest of your code works.

Comment: @user1816548 Updated the answer. If that is that reason for downvote, please remove.